# How to integrate GuiceServlet with Resteasy?

Tags: java, servlets, guice, resteasy

The official documentation provides example code: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html/Guice1.html . But I don't want to map ALL requests to go to the Resteasy servlet.
Is it possible to use GuiceFilter instead ? Something like:

```
serve("/resteasy-app/*").with(BlahBlahDispatcher.class);
```

p.s. sorry for my poor english

Comment: You should include all relevant code in your question instead of pointing to an external site, I think. That would make it easier for people to produce an answer.